# Which button when to used and which one is better practice to used in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

There are buttons out there in flutter, i am clear when to used TextButton but others button i don't understand to use it.Which one is better to used for better practice.

Comment: It mainly depends on how you want the button to look - You may find these articles helpful: https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/overview, https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Comment: And one more: https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TextButton** (older one - FlatButton) - mainly for showing text with button tap effect.

**ElevatedButton** (older one - Raised button) - shows the real button with tap effect.

**OutlinedButton** (older one - OutlineButton) - as the name suggests, it shows outline of the button with text and tap effect.

Comment: thats more helpful

Answer (score 0):

RaisedButton is deprecated, so please don't use it. Its updated alternative is ElevatedButton. We also use TextButton. If you wish to show any icon type Button, then use IconButton and customise the button shape.

Often I use a container and Widget like InkWell.